# Error Running .net core on Debian

Tags: c#, .net, linux, debian, .net-core

I'm trying to compile and run my first cross-platform app using .net core to migrate a c# app. I am trying to run this on Debian stretch 9.3

I've run both of these commands.

```
dotnet build -r debian-x64
dotnet publish -c release -r debian-x64

dotnet build -r linux-x64
dotnet publish -c release -r linux-x64
```

I get folders for each of these, (bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\linux-x64 and bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\debian-x64  respectively) which I used SFTP to copy to my linux box.
In linux, I cd into the folder and run .\program

**I get the following error while trying to use either the debian specific or generic linux compiled code.**

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (nfz_core.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'runtime.linux-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.App', version: '2.0.0'
    path: 'runtimes/linux-x64/lib/netcoreapp2.0/Microsoft.CSharp.dll'
```

I think I may have done something wrong in my csproj file, but I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong.

**Here is my .csproj file**

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;debian-x64;linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I appreciate any insight people could give.

Comment: "I get folders for each of these", what folder is this? Is this the `publish` folder or the other one?

Comment: Try to build from visual studio, copy `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0` folder to Linux, and run your app with `dotnet program.dll` command.
Also see this issue, could be relevant: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7543

Comment: @soonts I'll try that.

Comment: @omajid bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\linux-x64 and bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\debian-x64 respectively

Comment: Use the publish folder: `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\linux-x64\publish` instead. That is where the output of `dotnet publish` goes.

Comment: Oh, and to elaborate on what @Soonts says, there are two modes of publishing. `-r linux-x64` is self-contained deployment: you should copy the output of `publish` dir and run `./program` directly. Without `-r linux-x64`, it will assume a framework-dependent deployment and you will need to run `dotnet /path/to/your/dll` on the machine where you are deploying things. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/ for more information.

Comment: @omajid Thanks for clarification. I’d like to add that for my case (which was also Debian, but running on ARM) I wasn’t able to make self-contained deployment work. Framework dependent builds work flawlessly.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, that fixes it. I thought it was self contained. I guess, I was just using the wrong folder. Please post this as an answer so that I can give credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run:

```
dotnet publish -c release -r linux-x64
```

You are asking this code to be published as a [Self Contained Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd). That means all of .NET Core runtime, all your dependencies and basically anything not OS-related is published along with your application. The publish command puts your build under:

```
bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\linux-x64\publish
```

Note: This is *not* the same as `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\linux-x64\`. The `linux-x64` directory contains the output of `dotnet build`, not `dotnet publish`.

Once you copy over the `publish` directory, you can run your program directly (`./program`) on the target OS, without needing .NET Core installed.

An alternative is to run in [Framework Dependent Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli) mode. You build without `-r linux-x64` in that case. You still copy over the `publish` directory in that case, but you must run the application as `dotnet /path/to/your.dll`.

TLDR: Always copy the `publish` directory when deploying.

Answer (score 0):

@omajid's answer is helpful.

Note that if you wish to make a Framework Dependent Deployment (FDD), you must remove `<RuntimeIdentifiers>`/`<RuntimeIdentifier>` elements from your .csproj file.

Such FDDs are smaller as they don't bundle `*.so` and `System.*.dll` files, for example. For a minimal project, you will likely only have four files to deploy (three if you exclude `*.pdb` debug files). These deployments are portable between runtimes.